# make directory using variables problem

Tags: python, variables, directory

i can't make a directory using defined variables, i get an , `WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:`

i tried something like this:

```
import os, ConfigParser
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

exp_no = ""

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
resultado = config.get("General", "lugar_exp")

en1 = tk.Entry(root, width = 30, background = 'white', textvariable = exp_no)
en1.pack()

os.mkdir(resultado+'/'+en1.get())
```

Comment: First off, you can't just concatenate around a `/`, you need to use `os.path.join`. Second, what's the value of `resultado` and `en1.get()`?

Comment: ohh, thanks... i'm still a n00b...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that

```
os.mkdir(resultado+'/'+en1.get())
```

is running as

```
os.mkdir(resultado+'/')
```

because `en1.get()` might be empty or concatanation of paths is wrong which results in just `resultado`.

Could you verify that `en1.get()` contains something? And could you use `os.path.join`?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Windows is raising an error because the directory already exists.

You may want to add a bit more safety by checking for existence. Also [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) is a bit nicer in that it will create all missing directories on the path:

```
name = en1.get()
path = os.path.join(resultado, name)
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
```